# How to use TeamCity REST API to get the triggered build's buildId?

Tags: rest, teamcity, custom-build

I have triggered one custom build by TeamCity REST API:

`http://{buildServer}/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue={buildTypeId}`

But this http request hasn't any response message, so I can not know whether this build is running or in build queue.

Does any body know how to get that information by REST API?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can see the list of supported requests and names of parameters of REST API by using the following URL:

`http://{buildServer}/httpAuth/app/rest/application.wadl`

TeamCity 7.1 Onwards, you can check the status of the builds by using the following REST URL:

`http://{buildServer}//app/rest/builds/buildType:(id:btXXX)/statusIcon`

Read the complete REST documentation [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think this API can get status of the build which is already finished, but can not know one build is whether running or in queue.

Comment: I'm using a build locator with the `builds` action with `?locator=running:any` on the end of the URL to also get running builds, so I suspect this one works the same and you'll be able to use a build locator with `running:any`.

Comment: thanks! you are right, this one can get the finished and running build, but the builds in queue still can't get.